# Changing the position of page title on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, position

I'm a total amateur at both Wordpress and HTML/CSS so please excuse my lack of knowledge! I'm trying to recreate this site [www.fabiaclaris.com](http://www.fabiaclaris.com) in Wordpress, I've got the basics down of it but I'm struggling to get the title in the same position. This is what I've done so far in WP: [sidenav.ottilieclaris.com](http://sidenav.ottilieclaris.com)

I know how to rotate it but I've tried floating left etc but to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: Tila your question is confusing.

Comment: Inspect the original site via web inspector and try to build it the same

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using an image for the title as the original site does? If not, you could use the same image, place it before .menu-menu-1-container in your html, and float the image with float:left. The image will appear to the left of the menu as it does in the original site.

Comment: @scmssarty22 is correct! Notice that the example website contains the logo (name) as a "IMAGE", and yours is text inside a <H1>. 

Also if you're trying to recreate the same lay-out with Wordpress, you could consider a theme that has this feature build in. That will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using the image just because it seems a little old school but if it's more likely to work i'll try that! Thanks for the help guys, will try out and report back :)